# Unix Bash If else statement not working

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cmd

I am able to get answer in command prompt if just use IF condition alone.
But if add elif , the command prompt is still open & not ending...

Code I used...

```
-bash-3.00$ if [ "1" == "1" && "$cont" == "1" ]; then
> echo "I am if"
> elif [ "$cont" == "1"" ]; then
> echo "I am else"
> fi
>
>
```

**Expected Output :** It should end & return echo;

Comment: You hava a typo. `elif [ "$cont" == "1"" ]; then` One " too many

Comment: Is the double double-quote after 1 in the elif condition there on purpose?

Comment: Though i change it, -bash: [: missing `]'

Comment: Have you tried the version I suggest, @logan ?

Comment: just a note: "I am else" is not entirely true: else covers both the elif part and the else part of that elif, but you print "I am else" only in the elif part... could say "I am elif", and it would be "truer"

Comment: @OlivierDulac : Thanks for your comment... its just an example. do not think of any logic in printing some text...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change `&&` to `-a`:

```
$ cont=1
$ if [ "1" = "1" -a "$cont" = "1" ]; then echo "ha"; fi
ha
```

Or use two separate `[` commands:

```
$ if [ "1" = "1" ] && [ "$cont" = "1" ]; then echo "ha"; fi
```

Or use double brackets:

```
$ if [[ "1" == "1" && "$cont" == "1" ]]; then echo "ha"; fi
ha
```

Also note the `"` too many you have in your elif, as [RedX comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530844/unix-bash-if-else-statement-not-working#comment32510785_21530844).

Comment: Use Else if; I said, its working for IF alone...

still same: 
-bash-3.00$ if [ "1" == "1" -a "$cont" == "1" ]; then
> echo "I am if"
> elif [ "$cont" == "1"" ]; then
> echo "I am else"
> else
> echo "I am out"
> fi
>
>

Comment: He clearly has a typo in his code.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted.

Comment: This is correct, after the other typo is fixed. Since `&&` isn't recognized as the logical AND operator inside `[`, but *is* a shell control character, its presence will signal to `bash` that the preceding `[` command is missing its (stupidly) mandatory final `]` argument.

Comment: OK Sorry @RedX , deleting my comment!

Comment: Also, I corrected the original code: `==` should not be used with the `[` command. `bash` allows it, but it is not part of the POSIX spec. If you're going to use non-POSIX compatible code, you should use the superior `[[` command.

Comment: Its working fine now :)

Comment: Thanks, @chepner, that is pretty interesting. Is there any reference to know what's the most POSIX way of doing these comparisons? For example, what's best, `if [ cond1 ] && [ cond2 ]` or `if [ cond1 && cond2 ]`

Comment: I refer you to the [POSIX specification for the `test` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). `[ cond1 ] && [ cond2 ]` is the recommended POSIX-compatible expression (over the deprecated `[ cond1 -a cond2 ]`. `[ cond1 && cond2 ]` is just invalid. Specific to string equality, `=` is only operator supported by POSIX; `==` is an extension for the `[[` command that `bash` also allows with its built-in implementation of `test`; `/usr/bin/test foo == foo` will produce an error.

Answer (score 2):

`elif [ "$cont" == "1"" ]; then` isn't valid; quotes always have to come in pairs:

```
elif [ "$cont" == "1" ]; then
```

that gives you:

```
if [ "1" == "1" && "$cont" == "1" ]; then
echo "I am if"
elif [ "$cont" == "1" ]; then
echo "I am else"
fi
```

which fails with `bash: [: missing ']'`

The reason is the first line. You're using single `[` which means BASH sees:

```
if [ "1" == "1"
pipe (&&)
"$cont" == "1" ]; then
```

Try

```
if [[ "1" == "1" && "$cont" == "1" ]]; then
echo "I am if"
elif [[ "$cont" == "1" ]]; then
echo "I am else"
fi
```

The single `[` are an old <s>bug</s>feature from Bourne shell times. They produce all kinds of problems which were solved with the `[[...]]` syntax.

Unless you know what you're doing, avoid single `[` and the backtick syntax (use `$(cmd...)` instead).

Tip: To debug things like this, use `set -x` to have the shell print each command as it sees it.

Comment: Though i change it., It says missing ` ; 

-bash-3.00$ if [ "1" == "1" && "$cont" == "1" ]; then
> echo "I am if"
> elif [ "$cont" == "1" ]; then
> echo "I am else"
> else
> echo "I am out"
> fi
-bash: [: missing `]'
I am out
-bash-3.00$

Comment: @logan Do you have a space between the last quotation mark and the `]`?

Comment: @chepner : yes I have

Comment: @logan: See my improved answer.